# Simple products detached from configurabe products after import

Tags: magento2, importexport

I imported a simple spreadsheet into Magento 2.1.3 with stock updates and image updates. However, what this export seems to have also done is detach the simple products from the master configurable products for the items that were imported.

I tried to reconnect the simple products via a desktop application Magento Manager, however, this also failed as the products seem to still be associated with the configurable product in the database but not in the admin or website views.

Is there any way to either disconnect the simple products in the database and reconnect them so that they show up with the correct configurable product again.

Below I have added an example of which fields were added to the spreadsheet.
The import behavior was set to Add/Update only.

sku,    store_view_code,    attribute_set_code, product_type,   categories, product_websites,   name,   weight, product_online, tax_class_name, visibility, price,  url_key,    additional_attributes,  qty out_of_stock_qty,   additional_images,  base_image, small_image,    thumbnail_image swatch_image.